# Add item to ListView using the ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

Good evening everyone,

I am working on an android app and I have a (custom) ListView along with a custom ListAdapter. When I try to add data to the ListView by calling `.add()` on the ListAdapter, the app crashes immediately. I have tried to change the ListAdapter's data type to an ArrayList, but this didn't fix the problem.

My ListAdapter's code:

```
class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Device> {

public DeviceListAdapter(Context context, Device[] data) {
    super(context, R.layout.device_row, data);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View cv = li.inflate(R.layout.device_row, parent, false);

    Device dataItem = getItem(position);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView)cv.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    //TextView statusTextView = (TextView)cv.findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
    ImageView screenImageView = (ImageView)cv.findViewById(R.id.screenImageView);

    nameTextView.setText((String)dataItem.Name);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load((String)dataItem.ImageUrl).into(screenImageView);

    return cv;
}
```

}

Initializing the adapter and listview:

```
    Device[] data = new Device[]{};

    arad = new DeviceListAdapter(this, data);
    ListView deviceListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    deviceListView.setAdapter(arad);

    deviceListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String[] clickdata = (String[]) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, clickdata[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
```

Trying to add items to the listview:

```
arad.clear();
arad.add(devices);
```

**EDIT:** Made some changes to the code, Using custom Device class now instead of Object[]

Comment: What is ```devices``` ? Can you add the code?

Comment: what is the error?????

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
arad.add(devices.toArray());
```

Try,

```
arad.addAll(devices.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used the adapter like this, I think you should add to the array called `data` in your code, then notify the adapter.

```
data.add("Item X");//data.addAll(devices.toArray());
data.add("Item Y");
arad.notifyDataSetChanged();
```